# Why dynamically added JS and CSS doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

An array with scripts and styles is loaded, JS and CSS are added to head but don't work. See [screen here](https://ibb.co/RCCj5rM).

### Code

```
$.ajax({
  url:'https://gorodok.net.ua/api/NFTBot/php/get_payload.php',
  type:'get',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  data.forEach(function(src) {
  console.log(src)
  var  unknown;
  if (src.includes('.js')) {
     unknown = document.createElement('script');
     unknown.src = src;
     unknown.async = false;
     unknown.type = 'text/javascript';
   } else if (src.includes('.css')) {
    unknown = document.createElement('link');
    unknown.href = src;  
    unknown.async = false;
    unknown.type = 'text/css';
    unknown.rel = 'stylesheet';
  }
  document.head.appendChild(unknown);
  //document.body.appendChild(unknown);
});},
  error: function(error){console.log("EROR:" + error)}
});
```

If you add the same scripts and styles through the "explicit" array, everything is ok.

### Working code

```
["https://gorodok.net.ua/api/NFTBot/NFTBot.js","https://gorodok.net.ua/api/NFTBot/style/main.css"].forEach(function(src) {
  var  unknown;
  if (src.includes('.js')) {
     unknown = document.createElement('script');
     unknown.src = src;
     unknown.async = false;
     unknown.type = 'text/javascript';
   } else if (src.includes('.css')) {
    unknown = document.createElement('link');
    unknown.href = src;  
    unknown.async = false;
    unknown.type = 'text/css';
    unknown.rel = 'stylesheet';
  }
  document.head.appendChild(unknown);
});
```

Comment: There may be many reasons why it does not work as expected. Does the request generate an error? In this case the `success` function is called? Can you handle the error in an `error` function? If there is no error and the function is called, do you receive a valid json string (since you accept a json dataType)? How is that json formatted? Can you post an actual example?

Comment: ok, look i'm editing my question. And new screen: https://ibb.co/RCCj5rM

Comment: Is there any reason why in first example is document.body.appendChild(unknown); and in second document.head.appendChild(unknown);?

Comment: just tried different options, but not with `body` or `head` doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Answer: `async:false` - add setting to ajax

CODE:

```
$.ajax({
  async: false,
  url:'https://...',
  type:'get',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data){
```

....

.